# How to get an OnTriggerEnter2D to recognize objects entering it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create am endless jumper and I want to use a Cube to detect the Platforms and destroy them.

The problem I am having is that the Triggers aren't being recognized by these cubes.

[image]

The green is the destroy Cube.

[image]

I have the `RigidBody2D` and `BoxCollider2D`  on the destroyer.

```
public class DestroyPlatform : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnTiggerEnter2D (Collider2D collider)
    {
        Debug.Log("I am in the destroy Wall");
    }
}
```

This is the code I am using.  As I mentinoed I just want it to tell me it triggering.  I have seen tons of code on how to destroy it, but this basic code isn't working.

All of the platforms are 2D Sprites and are using the following:
[image]

Notice both GameObjects are triggers.  I have also tried to put the script on the platform prefabs and the destroyer cube.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think it's because you have isKinematic checked. I remember I had issues with that but can't remember if it resulted in triggers not being triggered... Alternatively, ensure your layers are able to interact with each other.

Comment: I unchecked all the Kinematic and it still isn't working.  Do I need to specify that the layers can work with one another?

Comment: Ok... It should, by default, be set up to interact with every layer unless you've changed it. It's in the project settings I think.

Comment: Are you sure the script is attached to one of the gameobjects? And have you turned the triggers off to check if they actually collide?

Comment: `OnTiggerEnter2D` should be `OnTriggerEnter2D`. Maybe thats the problem.

Comment: Oh, and I thought this was a Winnie the Pooh-themed game...

Comment: Well i guess it is kind of a Tigger :-(  I can't believe I did that.  Thanks!